# Eclipse with Tomcat7, where my application is running from?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, eclipse-mars

When working with **Apache Tomcat** I know to look for my `.war` file in `%CATALINA_HOME%/webapps`. Running **Eclipse MARS** with Tomcat plugin - the `webapps` directory is empty. 
Eclipse is installed at `C:/eclipse/` 
Tomcat is installed at `C:/tomcat7/`
Using *Windows 10* and *Java 1.8.0_131*
`JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/java/1.8.0_131/`
`CATALINA_HOME=C:/tomcat7/`
From where **Eclipse** with its **Tomcat plugin** is running my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting of the eclipse tomcat plugin (WTP) would configure a [separate server instance](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_does_WTP_support_separate_Tomcat_server_instances.3F) which its root folder is specified by `CATALINA_BASE`. This server instance will has its own configuration and webapps folder under `CATALINA_BASE`.

The value of the `CATALINA_BASE` can be configured from the following UI:

[image]

So , in the above configuration , the war will be deployed to `$project_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\`